# Query on IELTS score for express entry visa Canada

Tags: immigration, canada, ielts, language-test

I am a database administrator with 7+ years experience and final qualification is Masters of computer applications.

This is my IELTS Score and am the primary applicant

- Speaking: 6.0
- Listening: 7.0
- Writing: 5.5
- Reading: 9.0
- Overall score: 7.0

Clarify me whether I am eligible to apply for the express entry visa

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, you do not meet the [minimum language ability for English](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/language.asp). You must have Canadian Language Benchmark level 7 or higher. For IELTS, in the Writing category, that corresponds to a score of 6 or higher.

> Federal **Skilled Worker** Program
>
> You must meet the minimum level of Canadian Language Benchmark (CLB) 7
>   in English or Niveaux de compétence linguistique canadiens (NCLC) 7 in
>   French for your first official language in **all four** [emphasis
>   mine] language abilities.

The actual equivalency scores are [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/language-testing.asp). Scroll down and click the Federal Skilled Worker Program entry. The minimum score in each category/band is 6.0. The overall score is not used. You must take the General IELTS test, not the Academic one. This page also states that you cannot use an averaged score unless you have a disability and could not complete one of the sections.

The required scores for the **Skilled Trades** program are less--CLB 5 for speaking and listening and CLB 4 for writing and reading. That equates to [IELTS scores](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/language-testing.asp) of 5.0 or greater for CLB 5 and 3.5 for reading and 4.0 for writing.

There's a third category, **Canadian Experience Class**. The language requirement depends upon the [National Occupational Classification](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/noc.asp) (NOC) of the job.

```
NOC 0 or A job, the minimum level is CLB 7 (English) or NCLC 7 (French).
NOC B job, the minimum level is CLB 5 (English) or NCLC 5 (French).
```

Comment: Oops indeed, sorry, I guess all this is a bit too complex to me.

Comment: This is not your last chance. If possible re-appear for IELTS exam, But remember that the expectations from CIC immigration is pretty high, more than 886 points!!!

Answer (score -4):

You MUST apply for rechecking of your IELTS exam. You will get the correct score as I believe they messed up your result !

Comment: What makes you think that? Do you have some sort of source or reference to back this up?