# CLARIFICATION ON IELTS SCORE

Tags: canada, ielts, language-test

This is my IELTS Score and am the primary applicant.

```
Speaking:7.0
Listening:5.5
Writing:5.5
Reading:5.0
Overall score:7.0
```

Please clarify for me whether I am eligible to apply for the express entry visa.

Comment: [This one](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/4451/query-on-ielts-score-for-express-entry-visa-canada/4452#4452) is probably better one to use to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: The quick answer is no, because you need a minimum of 6.0 in each category, not just the overall score.