# My IELTS score and eligibility for Canada PR

Tags: canada, new-zealand, ielts

I am a software engineer with 8+ years of experience. My recent IELTS score was:

- Listening    6.50
- Reading  7.50
- Speaking 6.00
- Writing  6.00
- OverAllBandScore 6.50

Would I be able to apply for work visa for (a) Canada (b) New Zealand?

Comment: OK for Canada if you took the General test (not the Academic one). Also okay for [New Zealand](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/work/skilledmigrant/caniapply/english/) (overall band score of 6.5 with either General or Academic).

Comment: Note: I've added a bit of more explicit info to my answer on the [Query on  IELTS score](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/4451/query-on-ielts-score-for-express-entry-visa-canada) question.